# Disable function when search active with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery dropdown menu on the same page as a jQuery search box. When the user hovers over an image, the menu appears and then they move away it disappears.

I want to make it so the dropdown menu **doesn't** appear when the user hovers over the image when they are searching. How can I do this?

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to describe.

My code is;

```
$("#l").hover(function(){
    $("#l ul").show();
},function(){
    $("#l ul").hide();
});

$("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($("#s").val().length>0){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/"+t+".php?q="+q,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(c){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by searching do you mean when the form is submitted? Anyway, you can unbind the hover by

```
$("#l").unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')
```

Comment: it remove the hover action, then you have to rebind the event whenever you're done with your search, for example at success option for your ajax call

Comment: why not add 
$("#l").unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave').find('ul').hide();
if you're using jquery 1.7 you can also use off instead of unbind something like
$('#l').off('hover').find('ul').hide();